# Простой вопрос насчет оптимизации

Tags: kotlin

Если у меня есть такой код предположим:

```
if (array[i].length == 1) {
   var max = array[i].length
}
```

Имеет ли мне смысл до условия создавать переменную length, которая будет равна array[i].length, чтобы в случае прохождения условия опять не обращаться к длине строки? И чтобы не вышло, что программе пришлось это делать несколько раз. На сколько это нужно?

Comment: В данном случае достаточно сделать `var max = 1`. Может быть, стоит показать более жизненный пример ?

Comment: Оптимизация на спичках, имхо. Но лучше не повторяться кодом и заранее в переменной задать. Если вас волнует насколько долго выполняется код с `.length`, сделайте два цикла на триллионы итераций и в одном обращайтесь к `.length`, в другом -- до цикла задайте переменную и используйте переменную. А так, такие вещи компилятор сам может оптимизировать, например, убрав ненужное

Comment: Я наверное имею ввиду больше связанное со стандартом написания кода. Как лучше сделать ?

Comment: это совсем не нужно. array.lenght такая же переменная, что и вы создали бы сами - будет просто дублирование значения.

Answer (score 1):

На 50 миллиардах итераций разница в полсекунды:

```
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

fun main() {
    val iterations = 50_000_000_000
    val array = listOf("I", "am", "learning", "Kotlin")

    val time1 = measureTimeMillis {
        val index = 0
        for (iter in 0..iterations) {
            if (array[index].length == 1) {
                var max = array[index].length
            }
        }
    }
    println("Using .length: $time1 ms")
    val time2 = measureTimeMillis {
        val index = 0
        for (iter in 0..iterations) {
            val len = array[index].length
            if (len == 1) {
                var max = len
            }
        }
    }
    println("Using variable: $time2 ms")
}
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Using .length: 15821 ms
> Using variable: 15476 ms
> ```

Что и неудивительно, потому что str.length почти точно такая же переменная, как и любая другая.

Comment: Я наверное имею ввиду больше связанное со стандартом написания кода. Как лучше сделать ?

Comment: Да тут как больше нравится или как требуют стандарты компании.

Comment: Здается мне, `index` нигде не инкрементится, что дает простор компилятору так заоптимизировать байткод, что смысл такого теста совсем теряется :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Я сделал с инкрементом, но никакой разницы нет. Ни между двумя способами, ни между с инкрементом и без него. Или же что-нибудь упустил и компилятор опять все заоптимизировал сам :)